# Automatic Generation of DDL scripts

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, teradata

In real-time when an organization is trying to migrate from an on-prem Teradata to Snowflake, how to create all the objects in Snowflake? (Databases, Schemas, Tables and Views for ex).

Definitely one cannot create each object manually. (Lets say there are some 5000 odd tables). How is this automatic generation of DDL scripts done in real-time?
Also I am trying to avoid any 3rd party tools like Roboquery.

Comment: Something like [this](https://medium.com/@calvinpaul016/teradata-to-snowflake-migration-converting-the-code-ba03755369f8)?

Comment: During our migration process we used python script to convert the Teradata DDL to snowflake DDL

Comment: Is there a way you can share the template so I can get an idea on how it is done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can generate DDL Scripts using [`GET_DDL()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_ddl.html#get-ddl) function

You can find more information below

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_ddl.html

Answer (score 0):

Are You Possibly looking for something like this?

It will require more work to automate the process but here is the idea:
Iterate thru your information schema to get all the ddl content for each type DB/Table/Proc/View/etc.

Then automate this to push the results to a file, and then you can have an entire "Rebuild" script as you see fit.
This hopefully gets the idea going for what you might be looking for.

```sql
USE DATABASE SNOWFLAKE;
SELECT (
'USE DATABASE ' || CHAR(39) || DB.DATABASE_NAME || CHAR(39) || ';  ' ||
'SELECT GET_DDL(' || CHAR(39) || 'DATABASE' || CHAR(39) ||',' || CHAR(39) || DB.DATABASE_NAME || CHAR(39) || ', 1);' ||  CHAR(13) || CHAR(10)
) AS SHOW_DATABASE_DDLS 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATABASES AS DB;
```

It will generate all possibilities:

```sql
-- EXAMPLE
-- USE DATABASE 'ONEOFYOURDBS';  SELECT GET_DDL('DATABASE','ONEOFYOURDBS', 1);
```

The next layer down is tables/views this is subject to restrictions of each Database, so you MUST change databases and then you can run these for each database to get all your DDL's

```sql
USE DATABASE TESTDATABASE;
WITH CONFIG AS (
                    SELECT
                          '%'        AS TGT_DATABASE_FILTER
                        , '%'        AS TGT_SCHEMA_FILTER
                        , '%'        AS TGT_TABLE_FILTER
)
SELECT 
    (
        '/* =============================== AUTO-GENERATED FROM SCRIPT BEGIN =============================== */'       || CHAR(13) || CHAR(10) ||
        'SELECT GET_DDL(' || CHAR(39) || 'TABLE' || CHAR(39) ||', ' || CHAR(39) || CHAR(34) || 
        T.TABLE_CATALOG|| CHAR(34) || '.' || CHAR(34) || T.TABLE_SCHEMA || CHAR(34) || '.' || CHAR(34) || T.TABLE_NAME || CHAR(34) || CHAR(39) || ', 1);' || CHAR(13) || CHAR(10) ||
        '/* =============================== AUTO-GENERATED FROM SCRIPT END   =============================== */'      || CHAR(13) || CHAR(10) 
    ) AS INSERT_DML
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES          AS T
CROSS JOIN CONFIG                       AS C
WHERE UPPER(T.TABLE_TYPE)       = 'BASE TABLE'
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA             != 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'
  AND UPPER(T.TABLE_NAME)      LIKE UPPER(C.TGT_TABLE_FILTER)
  AND UPPER(T.TABLE_SCHEMA)    LIKE UPPER(C.TGT_SCHEMA_FILTER)
;
```

GENERATES: (THE , 1 produces the entire fully qualified path.)

```sql
/* =============================== AUTO-GENERATED FROM SCRIPT BEGIN =============================== */
SELECT GET_DDL('TABLE', '"TESTDATABASE"."TESTSCHEMA"."TESTTABLE"', 1);
/* =============================== AUTO-GENERATED FROM SCRIPT END   =============================== */
```

NOTES:

```
-- FYI 
SELECT CHAR(39);  -- SINGLE QUOTE
SELECT CHAR(34);  -- DOUBLE QUOTE
SELECT CHAR(13);  -- CARRIAGE RETURN
SELECT CHAR(10);  -- NEW LINE/LINE BREAK
```